# Setting SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND on a texture breaks rendering quality

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to create a texture A, make it transparent, and then render a texture B to the texture A. The problem is that to make the texture A transparent I have to first set SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND on the texture A, which, sadly, breaks the way the texture B is being rendered. I want to render multiple textures to the texture A, when I resolve the issue.

The texture B contains a white "New Game" text. The blue background is rendered separately.

Here is an image of the correct result, rendering texture B directly

[image: 1]

Here is an image of what I get rendering texture A without setting SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND.
[image: 2]

Here is an image of what I get rendering texture A  with setting SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND.
[image: 3]

I noticed that when using `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, 255, 255, 255, 0);` the texture B renders correctly, if the text is white, but it renders incorrectly when the text is black.

```
    texA = SDL_CreateTexture(r, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
                             SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET,
                             mWidth, mHeight);

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(r, texA);

    // breaks texB rendering, necessary to make texture transparent
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texA, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(r, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(r, NULL);

    SDL_RenderCopy(r, texB, NULL, NULL);

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(r, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a custom blend mode. Figured that out by accident, so I'm not sure why that works.

```
texA = SDL_CreateTexture(r, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
                         SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET,
                         mWidth, mHeight);

SDL_SetRenderTarget(r, texA);

const auto bm = SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode(
                        SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE,
                        SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,
                        SDL_BLENDOPERATION_ADD,

                        SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE,
                        SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,
                        SDL_BLENDOPERATION_ADD);
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texA, bm);

SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(r, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_RenderFillRect(r, NULL);

SDL_RenderCopy(r, texB, NULL, NULL);

SDL_SetRenderTarget(r, nullptr);
```